# Rails 5, Undefined method `for' for #<Devise on line devise_parameter_sanitizer.for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working with Rails 5

I aded new field username in model User.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:username)  
  end
end
```

During registration is displayed error: **undefined method `for' for # Did you mean? fork**

Trace:

NoMethodError (undefined method `for' for #
Did you mean?  fork):

```
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `configure_permitted_parameters'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (118.1ms)
```

Who can help? How solve this problem?

Comment: It happens on Rails 4.2 also.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

[`According to the documentation:`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

> The Parameter Sanitaizer API has changed for Devise 4

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

Comment: for some reason this works but when i restart rails it stops working again

Comment: @K2xL Clear your bin? Oops, its October. How did you fix this?

Comment: stop + restart spring, pehaps

Comment: Thanks! For those not wanting to update their code, you can just adjust your Gemfile accordingly - `gem 'devise', '~> 3'` sorted it for me.

Answer (score 34):

If you just change the `.for` to `.permit` it works as well. For example:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username) }
```

It works in both Rails 4.2.x and Rails 5.0.x

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])`

Comment: He did not forget, he needs to switch to new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you missed account_update in your controller's configure_permitted_parameters method, you need to follow the devise pattern. Devise has a an account update page. You can find this in views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb, and your code is also not going to work in the sign_up page, here you specified sign_up page**

To update your user table, the minute you submit an update in your users/edit, or if you are submitting a username in the sign_up page you need to follow this devise pattern, to update the database User table. Even if you added a new column to the user table, you would have to add it to the configure_permitted_parameters method. In your case it's username, but you missed account_update as well. You're basically saying that you want to update the username or add the string to username field without following the Devise pattern. Any field you add to the User table should follow this Devise pattern. Also you can specify which page is permitted to update this username. In my example below, i'm using the devise update page. So like I said, even if you added a custom field name to Users table you need to follow this pattern. If you have another page where you need to add username, you would just do the same thing.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

**Next make sure in your user.rb you have validate username in your User model.**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To update your user table, the minute you submit an update in your users/edit, or if you are submitting a username in the sign_up page you need to follow this devise pattern, to update the database User table. Even if you added a new column to the user table, you would have to add it to the configure_permitted_parameters method. In your case it's username, but you missed account_update as well. You're basically saying that you want to update the username or add the string to username field without following the Devise pattern. Any field you add to the User table should follow this Devise pattern. Also you can specify which page is permitted to update this username. In my example below, i'm using the devise update page. So like I said, even if you added

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_paramters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_paramters

        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:fullname])

        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:fullname, 
        :phone_number, :description, :email, :password])

    end

end
```