# Why am I getting error: 'undefined method "for" '?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I am trying to add a new column to the devise user model. But I'm getting an error to this file. I ran a migration to change the column, added the text fields to the view already. Thank you

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if:        :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

     if params[:action] == 'update'
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)}
    else
        if params[:action] == 'create'
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
            |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
        }
    end
  end

 end
```

Comment: Looks like devise has changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341967/rails-5-undefined-method-for-for-devise-on-line-devise-parameter-sanitizer

Answer (score 0):

## Parameter Sanitizer API has changed for Devise 4

[**Documentation for Devise 4**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

You need to replace `for` with `permit`:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
    }
```

[**Documentation for Devise 3**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/3-stable#strong-parameters)

Your current method should work in Devise 3 i.e :

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params)
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

**for** method is deprecated in the latest devise version , so you need to use **permit** instead of for